# Getting "character buffer object" error in python when using str.index( )

Tags: python, string, indexing

I'm trying to sort through a string, and I keep getting the error:

TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Here is my code:

```
        if number.index(i) in guess and not number.index(i) == guess.index(i):
            replace(guess.index(i),'COW')

        if number.index(i) == guess.index(i):
            replace(guess.index(i),'BULL')
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Change `i` to `str(i)` and post the next error that you get. What is `replace`?

Comment: @Blender: string method disguised as a function; see the original question.